# как решить ошибку telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 404. Description: Not Found

Tags: python, telegram-bot

писал простенького телеграм бота и столкнулся с ошибкой.

Как её решить?

```
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: 
A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. 
Error code: 
404. Description: Not Found
```

Вот код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot('%5773397252:AAFeuY70n9B_Rxej7qr7pdeOwmkfgcXadZ4%')
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
if message.text == "Новости мира":
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "в разработке")
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ошибка в токене(не только там, но это та о которой вы спросили)
проверьте в botfather токен и вставьте его

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

tokken = ''#токен сюда
bot = telebot.TeleBot(tokken)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Новости мира":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "в разработке")

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

поправил еще немного код, в вашем вы не следовали табуляции